# Definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a graded ring, and let $X = Proj S$, we define the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ to be $S(n)^\sim$. Here can you explain what $S(n)$ is?

Comment: The answer is a bit boring: $S(n)$ has the same $S$-module structure as $S$ but the graduation now is different. What was of degree $d$ before know is of degree $d-n$, i.e, $S(n)_{d}=S_{d+n}$. For example you can see the [Stack project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JL)

Comment: @Yesterdaywasdramatic Is there a motivation for that?

Comment: Of course but that is a more subtle question and there are different ways to answer it. One possible answer is that one can prove that $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ is a locally free sheaf of rank one and this sheaves are really nice. These are the analogue of the line bundles in differential geometry. The set of line bundles of $X$ is so important that it has its own name: $Pic(X)$. It has a group structure (the picard group) and one of the central problems is to understand this group. For example for $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ the group is cyclic and $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ is the generator.